# Binding String with a label.Text on ContentView inside ListViewItem

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, binding, xamarin.forms

I have a ContentPage with a ViewModel. This view contains a ListView.

On XAML i have

```
    <ListView>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate:>
            <templates:miItemView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

On MiItemView i have other contentView with a Label. How can binding text property of this label with a String property of my ViewModel????

My ViewModel:

```
public class RoutePageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Views
    private List<Citizen> _citizens;
    private int _citizensPosition;
    #endregion

public List<Citizen> Citizens
    {
        get { return _citizens; }
        set
        {
            _citizens = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public String CitizensPosition 
    {
        get { return _citizensPosition; }
        set
        {
            _citizensPosition = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

my ItemView:

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <Grid
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            RowSpacing="0"
            VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <Grid>

            <!--  Name  -->
            <Label
                    x:Name="myTitle"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <!--  AGE  -->
                <Label
                        FontSize="Small"
                        Text="{Binding Age}" />
        </Grid>
        <local:PositionIndicatorView
                />
    </Grid>
```

And PositionView:

```
<StackLayout>
            <Label Style="{StaticResource labelGeneralStyle}" Text="HOW BINDING WITH CitizensPosition />
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `CitizensPosition` be part of `Citizen`? Then you can just bind it like you bind `Age` and `Name`

Comment: I don't sure. Really i need two Propertys , CitizensPosition (position of item) and TotalItems (total of list). What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Gerald you should have CitizenPosition as an attribute of your Citizen model. This is where it should be because it will have a different value for each Citizen (as opposed to the TotalItems, which has a single value for the whole list). You haven't included the code to initialize your list of Citizens, but you could assign a position value to each Citizen before binding your list.

You are complicating matters by using a separate view for your PositionView - why not just make that part of your ItemView xaml? Then you could bind directly to CitizenPosition just like you do with the Age and Name labels.

If a separate view is required, you'll need to add a bindable property to your PositionView to set the value so you can bind to it. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47160027/15904) for more details, or see the [Xamarin bindable properties documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties/).